# Effective way of drawing image using java Graphic2D?

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

How to effectively draw the following image with java Graphic2D ? Just like c++ performance .

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Make BufferedImage as big as draw panel
2. Draw entities on created BufferedImage
3. Draw BufferedImage on draw panel